# Snapshot testing in Spring MVC test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc, spring-mvc-test

Is there any existing solution for doing snapshot testing [1] in Spring MVC test (MockMvc)?

Something like:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/users")
  .andExpect(status().isOk())
  .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
  .andExpect(matchesSnapshot("__snapshots__/users/list.json"));
```

Running this test first time would make test pass and write response content to `src/main/resources/__snapshots__/users/list.json`.

Running this test second time compares response content to `src/main/resources/__snapshots__/users/list.json`. If it's the same, it passes. Otherwise, it fails.

[1] https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing

Answer (score 2):

[selfie](https://selfie.dev/jvm) is a snapshot testing library available on the JVM.

- it can do snapshots on disk or as [inline literals](https://selfie.dev/jvm#literal)
- it garbage-collects unused disk snapshots [automatically](https://github.com/diffplug/selfie/blob/main/selfie-runner-junit5/src/main/kotlin/com/diffplug/selfie/junit5/SelfieGC.kt)
- easy to [control read/write](https://selfie.dev/jvm/get-started#quickstart) without any CLI flags, run like a regular test
- (advanced) you can snapshot multiple facets of an entity, and then assert some on disk and others inline to [tell a story](https://selfie.dev/jvm/advanced#harmonizing-disk-and-inline-literals)

The story example linked above uses Jooby, but the same thing applies to Spring - easy to put different aspects of the MockMVC data into different facets.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Zenika/java-snapshot-matcher

Snapshot testing with Java:

We use Jackson to handle serialization/deserialization to JSON format. This library therefore can handle any object that is serializable by Jackson.

Real world example:

I want to test a converter, which transforms a Planet into a PlanetDTO.

```
@Component
public class PlanetConverter {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public PlanetDTO convertPlanet(Planet planet) {
        PlanetDTO dto = objectMapper.convertValue(planet, PlanetDTO.class);

        dto.films = planet.filmsUrls.stream()
                .map(filmUrl -> restTemplate.getForObject(filmUrl, FilmDTO.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        dto.residents = planet.residentsUrls.stream()
                .map(filmUrl -> restTemplate.getForObject(filmUrl, PeopleDTO.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return dto;
    }
}
```

As it can be difficult to generate input object and to perform assertions on returned object, we use the snapshot matcher to handle assertions.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PlanetConverterTest {

    // RestTemplate needs to be mocked to ensure stability of snapshots.
    // Note that ObjectMapper is not mocked
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private PlanetConverter converter;

    // Create input objects from JSON files
    private PeopleDTO lukeSkywalker = fromJson("luke-skywalker", PeopleDTO.class);
    private FilmDTO attackOfTheClones = fromJson("attack-of-the-clones", FilmDTO.class);
    private Planet tatooine = fromJson("tatooine", Planet.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Mock return values of RestTemplate
        when(restTemplate.getForObject("https://swapi.co/api/people/1/", PeopleDTO.class))
                .thenReturn(lukeSkywalker);
        when(restTemplate.getForObject("https://swapi.co/api/films/5/", FilmDTO.class))
                .thenReturn(attackOfTheClones);
    }

    @Test
    public void converterTest() {
        // Call method
        PlanetDTO planet = converter.convertPlanet(tatooine);

        // Do assertion
        assertThat(planet, matchesSnapshot());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of java-snapshot-matcher. I'm looking for something with first-class support for MockMvc.